# how to load math equations correctly with mathjax in angular6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, mathjax

I am loading mathematical equations correctly with following code. I want to use it in angular. How to convert it in angular

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML' async></script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
   MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("TeX Jax Ready",function () {
     MathJax.Hub.Insert(MathJax.InputJax.TeX.Definitions.macros,{
       cancel: ["Extension","cancel"],
       bcancel: ["Extension","cancel"],
       xcancel: ["Extension","cancel"],
       cancelto: ["Extension","cancel"]
     });
   });
   </script>

    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
      MathJax.Hub.Config({
       TeX: {
       noErrors: {disabled: true}, // Show error messages
       MAXBUFFER: 25*1024, // Set size of buffer in bytes
      },
      tex2jax: {
       inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
       processEscapes: true
     }
   });
   </script>
```

Comment: TRY THIS PACKAGE `https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-katex`

Comment: this plunker should help you `http://embed.plnkr.co/qBRAIxR27zK3bpo6QipY/`

Answer (score 1):

I have loaded the code in the index.html in angular and my problem is solved

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?
config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML' async></script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
   MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("TeX Jax Ready",function () {
    MathJax.Hub.Insert(MathJax.InputJax.TeX.Definitions.macros,{
       cancel: ["Extension","cancel"],
       bcancel: ["Extension","cancel"],
       xcancel: ["Extension","cancel"],
       cancelto: ["Extension","cancel"]
   });
   });
 </script>

<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
```